# Active redshift user count for specific time period

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need Active redshift user count for specific time period (say 20th Apr to 25th May).

I know PG_user table, but know luck with what i am looking for.
All on all i need a report with active user count for specific time period (20th Apr to 25th May).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to know how many user where logged in that time period?
to get the list day by day

```
 select  starttime, process, user_name
 from stl_sessions where starttime>='2017-04-20' starttime <'2017-05-26'
```

to count users in total during that period:

```
 select  count(*)
 from stl_sessions where starttime>='2017-04-20' starttime <'2017-05-26'
```

Comment: Hello MiloBellano, Thanks for the update, However this is redshift system table/view and holds only last 15 days of data. Hence no able to pull the active user count in the mentioned time period.

 select  max(starttime),min(starttime)
 from stl_sessions

Result :
max                                 min
2017-06-08 13:00:49 2017-05-24 15:13:50

Answer (score 0):

STL system views retain seven days of log history. If you want to store log data for more than 7 days, you have to periodically copy it to other tables or unload it to Amazon S3.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_intro_STL_tables.html